# Use of "to be having"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am confused with the usage of "to be having".

He is assumed to be having the diamonds.

or

He is assumed to have the diamonds.

Which one is correct?

Comment: This is not about "to be having". This is about _assume_, the verb which is governing the complement in this case. _Assume_ can take an infinitive complement direct object with B-Raising, but that construction requires Passive: _*[Indef] assumes him to have/be having the diamonds_ is ungrammatical, but _He is assumed (by Indef] to have/be having the diamonds_ is fine. Whether the infinitive is plain or progressive depends on what the speaker means, as TrevorD points out.

Comment: +1 @JohnLawler Thanks for adding the grammatical analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Both can be correct: they mean different things.

> ***He is assumed to be having the diamonds.***

Although the sentence could be re-phrased slightly, in essence, this means that it is assumed he will be receiving the diamonds; that they should be being sent to him; that they are meant to be given to him; etc..
In other words, this implies an assumption that something *will be* - or *is meant to be* - happening, probably *in the near future*.

> ***He is assumed to have the diamonds.***

This means that it is assumed that they are *already* in his possession - *now*; *present tense*.